# Kalman filters (mean-squared prediction, optimum decision rule)

Tags: random-variables, kalman-filter

Consider the model
\begin{align*}
X_{k+1} &= 1/2X_k + U_k\\
Y_k &= \theta X_k + V_k
\end{align*}

where $X_k$'s are scalar, $U_0,U_1.\dotsc$ are i.i.d $N(0,q)$ random variables, $V_0,V_1,\dotsc,$ are i.i.d $N(0,r)$ random variables, $X_0$ is a $N\left(0,\sum_0\right)$ random variable, and all $U_k$'s, $V_k$'s, and $X_0$ are independent of one another.

(a) Suppose $\Theta ≡ 1$ and $r = q = 1$. Find the initial state variance $\sum_0$ such that the optimal prediction filter, i.e. $\hat{X}_{t+1|t}$, is time-invariant. Write the recursion for $\hat{X}_{t+1|t}$ in this case. What is the mean-squared prediction error for this case?

(b) Suppose $r = q = 1$ and $\sum_0$ is the answer from part (a). What is the structure of the optimum decision rules for deciding $\Theta = 0 $ versus $\Theta = 1 $ based on observations for $k = 0,1,\dotsc,n$?